# I am trying to recreate my desktop wallpaper into a website and I've encountered a problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

How can I launch applications from node.js? I tried using child processes but as far as I understand they only work with small scripts and arent going to launch a game or a full application.

Comment: I can launch a whole Desktop environment via NodeJS, not sure why you think child_process is limited to small scripts.

Comment: Do you use spawn or exec to do that?

Comment: irrelevant, unless you use the *sync* version, which is *not* what you should use.

Comment: Thank you, I used the `start` command with child_precess exec function and it worked.